# Change of scalars for comodules as adjunctions?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, hopf-algebras, coalgebras, comodules

Let $k$ be a commutative ring and $f: C \to C'$ be a homomorphism of $k$-coalgebras (for simplicity, we can suppose that it is surjective so that $f(C) = C'$). There is a functor:
$$f_*: {}^lC-comod \to {}^lC'-comod$$
$$(M, \Delta_M) \mapsto (M, \Delta_M' := (f \otimes id_M) \circ \Delta_M)$$
wherein $\Delta_M$ denotes the left-$C$-coaction on $M$. Does this functor admit left/right-adjoints, and if so, do these left/right-adjoints have concrete descriptions ?

**Question edited according to comments by

Mariano Suárez-Álvarez**

Comment: Your *evident* functor is not quite as evident as you seem to think... What is $f(C)\otimes_k M$?!

Comment: There is a functor from C comodules to C' comodules which maps a C comodule M with coaction $\lambda$ to the C' comodule which as a vector space is again M but whose C' coaction is the composition $f\otimes 1_M\circ\lambda$. This is the functor of change-of-coalgebras.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez I'm more or less brand new to comodules. Please feel free to edit the question if you think there's a mistake or if I was being unclear. Thank you!

Comment: You are being unclear, and since I cannot tell what you are asking I cannot edit your question, for i don't know what you want to ask! You apparently have a functor in mind: explain what it does to objects better.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez I have edited my question according to your comment. Hopefully it's clearer now.

Comment: Ok. Now, there is a similar functor for modules: do you know if it has adjoints and what do they look like?  Not everything works the same with comodules as with modules, but it always helps to see what happens with modules...

Comment: If $\varphi: A \to A'$ is a $k$-algebra homomorphism (and let's say we're regarding $A'$ as an $(A', A)$-bimodule via $f$) then the functor you're referring to is that one that sends $(M, \pi)$ (with $\pi$ being the left-$A$-action on $M$) to $(M, \pi')$, where $\pi'$ is the left-$A'$-action on $M$ given by $\alpha_1 \otimes (\alpha_2 \otimes m) = \alpha_1 \alpha_2 \otimes m$, right ? It has a right-adjoint, given by $Hom_{A'}(A', -)$.

Comment: Notice that that Hom functor is essentially the identity.